# cURL Save File to Server With Mime Type Check

Tags: php, curl, mime-types, fopen

I am creating an internal tool for my team that will allow trusted team members to save remote files to our server via php and curl. I have the open, write, and close working perfectly, but I would like to add a check to make sure the file is of a certain mime type before it creates and writes the local file.

How could I do this, based on an array of mime types?

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen($local_file, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I hope you know that the mime type that the server sends is configurable on that server's end. E.g. anybody with php can set whatever mime-type they want. You may want to check the file extension, or use a utility like "file" to check the contents

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by checking the mime via fileinfo after the file has been transfered. If it is not a valid mime type, then I remove it.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen($local_file, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime_type = $finfo->file($local_file);

if (strpos($mime_type, 'application/xml') === false) {
    unlink($local_file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);

$mime = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

in `$mime` has mime type of file.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky! You could download the whole file first (into memory, or a temporary folder.) If you want to stream it, you may have to:

1. set CURLOPT_HEADER to include the HTTP response headers in the data you get back
2. set CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION instead of CURLOPT_FILE, read and parse the http headers to see the mime type, and then decide if you're going to create/write a file or not.

Obviously this is quite a bit of work, as you'll have to do some basic parsing of the HTTP headers, and possibly buffering to get the whole HTTP headers at once.

Hopefully someone will post an easier solution.

pseudocode:

```
state = headers
buf = ''
fd = null
func writefunc(ch, data)
   if state is headers
      buf .= data
      div = buf.strpos "\r\n\r\n"
      if div !== false
         mime = get_mime buf, div
         if mime_ok mime
            fd = fopen ...
            fd.write buf.substr div+4
            state = saving
         else
            # returns other than data.length() abort connection
            return 0
  else
     fd.write data
  return data.length()
```

Comment: What if the servers don't pass Content-Type? And what I want to check the filesize before I download it?

Comment: mime_ok would return false if there's no mime type. HTTP protocol doesn't always send Content-Length.